# Proper way to create a zfs off an existing directory?

Tags: filesystems, solaris, zfs, sun

Lets say I have an rpool with etc/ as a regular directory within it and now I want to create a separate zfs rpool/etc, obviously inheriting all the data I had in original /etc.

What would be the most proper and safe way to do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't supported to turn `/etc` into its own zfs file system.

The reason is that `/etc` is needed during the early stages of boot, before (Open)Solaris starts to mount zfs file systems, so it would be empty if you change it.

My guess is that you want to take snapshots of `/etc`, but you can just take snapshots of the root file system instead:

```
zfs snapshot rpool/ROOT/opensolaris
```

You may have to replace `opensolaris` with the name of the current boot environment (run `beadm list` to find out which)

Comment: ok, what about any other directory, then? say, rpool/zones/myzone/export/home/git? :)

Comment: If you want to turn your git directory into a zfs filesystem, you just need to make tar archive of the current contents, then "rm -rf" the git dir, after that run "zfs create -o mountpoint=/path/to/git rpool/path/to/whatever/git" and finally untar the saved files.

Comment: oh, ok, that's what I thought... but secretly hoped there was a transparent way to split zfs :)

Answer (score 11):

There isn't a built-in or automated way to create a new DataSet and migrate existing data to it.  To get it done you'll need to create the dataset and manually (e.g. rsync) the data to it.

Let's say you have a dataset named `tank\set` with a directory in it named `folder`.  You want to 'promote' the folder to be a child dataset named `tank\set\folder`:

```
mv /mnt/tank/set/folder /mnt/tank/set/folder-backup # move this out of the way so the new dataset doesn't mount on top of it
zfs create tank/set/folder
rsync -aAX /mnt/tank/set/folder-backup/ /mnt/tank/set/folder # bring over all the old data including acls and attributes
```

Then review that the data looks good; take a snapshot of the parent dataset just in case, and delete the `folder-backup` directory.

Answer (score 1):

A pretty Sick but may useful idea:

What if I make a clone of an existing dataset `tank\set` as `tank\folder`

it will be exactly as `tank\set` which contains what I want: `tank\folder\folder` and also massive other things.

And then, I can remove anything I don't want from `tank\folder` and after all, `mv tank\folder\folder\* tank\folder\` , which will be in-filesystem-move only, and should finish in seconds.

I'll test it in a day or two

---

I'm afraid that rm -rf takes longer than I thought.

an option to use after all.